# I don’t think cycles is working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency, glass

So last night I was trying to make a crystal structure like the one in ducky3d’s video about fantasy crystals. I am very new to blender so bear with me. The transparency doesn’t work and I never see the lights do anything either. I’ve tried switching to cycles but nothing happened at all. Maybe it has to do that my computer is a lump of sh*t because it only has 2GB RAM and 1.4GHz
and 64 GB of ssd. My computer could be the problem but I doubt it because eevee works quite fast for my computer being so bad. So I’m starting to believe that cycles, when I turn it on, just doesn’t turn on. Any help would be appreciated because I am very frustrated and tired. I spent all night trying to figure this out. Thanks!

EDIT

I textured the inner crystal just now but it's not showing up on the layout or final render. I am starting to loose my patience because I have textured the inside, didn't work. I tried to make the outside transparent, Didn't work. I really need help.

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image] [image]

and here's my .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Blender!  It's a big, complicated piece of software where lots of things can go wrong, and it takes a lot of practice to get used to it, so no real surprise that you had a tough night working on this.

In the posted .blend file, the "inner crystal" had no material, so maybe you uploaded it before shading it green and blue.

The "outer clear part of crystal" did have a reasonable glass material.  It looked like this in my Cycles preview, with a fuzzy version of the inner crystal just visible.  Did it look anything like this for you?

[image]

If so, the main problem with the "outer clear part of crystal" material is probably the high roughness which makes it look pretty opaque.  If I turn the roughness value down to 0.25 in the principled shader, add a blue emission shader material to the "inner crystal", kick the area light strength up from 1 to 50 (i.e. 5000 Watts), and add a couple duplicate area lights, also 5000 Watts, it starts to look better.

[image]

Here's a .blend file with the changes I made.  If you load this up, switch to the "Rendered" view, and don't see a blue crystal like the image above, then yes, something's wrong with Cycles running on your admittedly underpowered computer.

[image]

Note that it looks even better if I select both the inner and outer crystal and stretch them out on the Z-axis ("s" to size, "z" to size along Z-axis, and move the mouse to stretch it vertically before left clicking).  The longer crystal reflects light better.

Getting this scene working with Eevee would be tough.  Eevee doesn't do a great job with accurate handling of area lights and glass materials.  But, you could try the following:

- In the Render Properties panel, switch your Render Engine from Cycles to Eevee.  Further down in the panel, click on the "Screen Space Reflections" checkbox, open that subpanel, and check the "Refraction" checkbox.
- Click on your "outer clear part of crystal", go to its Material Properties panel, and scroll down to the "Settings" subpanel.  In that subpanel, change "Blend Mode" from "Opaque" to "Alpha Blend", and below that turn on the "Screen Space Refraction" checkbox.

Switch to the Render view, and you should have something like this:

[image]

It looks pretty ugly and underwhelming, though it does look kind of cool if you middle-mouse-button drag the view around.

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: So, mine does not look like that picture at all. I think it’s my computer. And also, when you said it has no material, what do you mean by that? And how do I put material into it?

Comment: Ah, too bad.  With regard to the material, at 1:21 in the video, Ducky 3D is working on the inner crystal and says "I'm going to remove the material [clicks "-"] and add a new one [clicks "New"]".  In the .blend file you posted, it looks like you removed the material but didn't (yet) add a new one.

Comment: I am still confused by that because he went so fast in the video I couldn’t tell what he was doing.

Comment: With the inner crystal selected, and the "Material Properties" panel open in the bottom right, he scrolls to the top of the "Material Properties" panel, clicks on the minus sign (`-`) in the top right, which deletes the inner crystal's existing material, and then he clicks on the "New" button to add a fresh new material.

Comment: Also, note that for YouTube videos, if you click on the gear-shaped icon in the bottom right corner of the playback screen (it's in the row of icons for closed captioning, fullscreen, etc.), one of the settings is "playback speed".  I've personally watched parts of tutorials at 0.25x speed ten or fifteen times to figure out exactly what someone was doing.

Comment: Thanks! That is a really good idea.

Comment: DANG IT. I had the material in the inner part and the - sign deleted it :( I spent a lot making those colors on the inner part. Btw the color was not showing up in the final render or in layout so thats another problem. I am going to start over and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101824/discussion-between-tmax-and-k-a-buhr).